# Absolutely positioned container size miscalculated with canvas as its child

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have a `canvas` element wrapped inside an absolutely positioned `div`:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.shape > canvas {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

The canvas has a ratio of 1x1. The height of the absolutely positioned container is 100% of the body height, and is 100px. The size of the canvas in this case should be 100x100px. So should be the size of its parent absolutely positioned container (filled with green). Everything works OK in Chrome, however Firefox ignores the recalculated width of the canvas element and uses its inline width value to size the parent absolutely positioned container. Why is that?

Comment: it's a very complex case where we need to combine the spec of percentage height, replaced element, absolute positionned element ... technically, Firefox is correct but I would say that Chrome is doing an extra effort